# Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #14: invalid drawable tag gradient

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

```
 val cardImage = creditCardModel?.let { cardHelper.getCardImage(it) }
 cardImage?.let { ivCardImage.setImageResource(it) }
```

***ic_salepluscard.xml***

```
<vector android:autoMirrored="false"
android:height="130dp"
android:viewportHeight="130"
android:viewportWidth="288"
android:width="288dp"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group>
    <clip-path android:pathData="M0,0h288v130h-288z M 0,0" />
    <group>
        <clip-path android:pathData="M0,0h288v130h-288z M 0,0" />
        <path android:pathData="M0,0H288V130H0Z">
            <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
                <gradient
                    android:endX="234.72"
                    android:endY="179.66"
                    android:startX="26.496"
                    android:startY="-15.08"
                    android:type="linear">
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF60707A"
                        android:offset="0" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF181F23"
                        android:offset="0.323" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF88959D"
                        android:offset="0.678" />
                    <item
                        android:color="#FF181F23"
                        android:offset="1" />
                </gradient>
            </aapt:attr>
        </path></vector>
```

***Logcat errors:***

*android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_saleplusplatinumkart.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020250. If the resource you are trying to use is a vector resource, you may be referencing it in an unsupported way. See AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled*

*android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_saleplusplatinumkart_1.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020373*

*Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #14: invalid drawable tag gradient*

I tried everything but I couldn't find a solution.Can you help me how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by androidx solved? Atleast explain how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 val drawable: Drawable = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(this, R.drawable.radius_stroke_cat)
```